# Android Q. DocumentFile.delete method

Tags: android, android-10.0

DocumentFile.delete method will remove entry from MediaStore?

From API reference 
*boolean delete ()
Deletes this file.
Note that this method does not throw IOException on failure. Callers must check the return value.
Returns
boolean true if this file was deleted, false otherwise.*

Comment: I would not assume that it does. At best, it would depend on the document provider that supplied the `Uri` that you are using with `DocumentFile`.

Comment: @CommonsWare tried a few things. 1) contentResolver.delete -> no rows getting deleted. 2)checked MediaStore entry for before and after DocumentFile.delete. result - entry present before delete and entry remove after delete. tested in emulator, android Q. Not sure if this will happen in all api29 devices.

Comment: this is the reply i got from issuetracker.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138887165

Comment: [The source code](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/documentfile/documentfile/1.0.1-source/androidx/documentfile/provider/SingleDocumentFile.java.html) does not show `DocumentFile` doing anything with the `MediaStore`. It just uses `DocumentsContract`. At best, `DocumentsContract` could get rid of a `MediaStore` entry for the specific `Uri` that you are deleting. If the underlying *file* is indexed in the `MediaStore`, or if there is a different `Uri` that points to that same content that is indexed in the `MediaStore`, `DocumentsContract` cannot clean those up.

Comment: @CommonsWare the above source code is from API29, latest release ?

Comment: `DocumentFile` is not a framework class. It comes from a library. The page that I linked to is from `androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1`, the current stable version of the library.

Comment: @CommonsWare So there is no way to remove mediastore entry? ontentResolver.delete is not working in Q.

Comment: "So there is no way to remove mediastore entry?" -- usually, a `MediaStore` entry is for a particular file on the filesystem. That is up to the `MediaStore` and the owner of the file (e.g., the `DocumentsProvider`) to manage. If the `DocumentsProvider` is simply deleting the file,  the `MediaStore` should eventually find out about the change. If the `DocumentsProvider` deletes the entry from `MediaStore` itself, that would be better, but not all `DocumentsProvider` implementations will do that. Regardless, your app has little to do with any of it.